# Converting html webpage into a pdf page(pdf file which user will download)

Tags: php, html, cakephp, pdf, pdf-generation

I am developing a website in Cakephp framework, what i want to do, is to give the user option of downloading the page he is viewing in pdf format.I am using html2pdf plugin but its giving problem integrating with Cakephp. How can i solve this. Thanx for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

Try TCPDF. It is simple and powerful enough.

Comment: I can only agree, TCPDF is simple to implement but you might want to have an indication that the page is loading (simple gif) as we had users tell us it didn't work (while it was loading about 25 pages)

Comment: @admseipsum: Thanx adseipsum, i tried it. But as my website requires authentication, when i am using 
$Pdf->process(Router::url('/', true) . 'mis/view/'. $id);
this i guess is creating a new session to access the view, because of this i am getting redirected to login page, hence getting the login page in my downloaded pdf file. Is there any way i can tackle this. Really thanx for showing your interest. :)

Comment: Why you try to send file direct to the view?

Answer (score 1):

Two options, one is paid and another open source. Both are good, and well documented.

1. [PDFLib](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php)
2. [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

I would suggest starting with FPDF, and then learning/moving to PDFLib

Answer (score 1):

Using [DOMPDF](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/&ei=GnhoT8TFGIes8QOupMCPCQ&usg=AFQjCNHuyJxDRFntZXtCt090UUUH5YgAhQ&sig2=OjpwNOZUuIIQrdsdTIjIwg).

**Example Code :**

```
<?php
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $html = "<h1>some document</h1>";

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);  
    $dompdf->set_paper('A4');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("pdfReport.pdf");
?>
```